# Fragment Is shown part of the time

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have A navigation drawer with several fragments in the menu, in the first fragment when an item is pressed in a gridView i want to start a different fragment, i get no error , but sometimes the fragment is shown and sometimes it's not shown,

thc calling fragment is HomeFragment:

the opend fragment is InstrumentsFragment ,

here is the container layout:  drawr layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

all the other fragments beside InstrumentsFragment are called form an activity: with this method:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FirstFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new SecondFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new SearchDbFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new ThirdFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

so from HomeFragment to InstrumentsFragment i'm calling in this way:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new InstrumentsFragment(), "InstrumentsFragment"); 
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

and i'm getting no error! , just sometimes it works and sometimes it dosn't!
what can be the problem?

EDIT:

full code:

the class that contains the navigation drawer:

```
public class MainOptionsActivity extends Activity 
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    ArrayList<String> resultCompanys = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> resultModels = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> resultPrices = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> resultStores = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> resultUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> followedObjIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> urlsForUpdate = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean changeInFollowedItems = false;
    String currentUrl = "";
    String[] urlsArray = {"http://www.music-","http://www.kolhamusica" , "http://www.diez.co"};
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    protected OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;
    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    int locationOfCompany = 0 , fragmentIdFromIntent = -1;
    String tmpCompany = "";
    CustomAdapter followsAdapter;

    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    String urlToFetchFrom = "" ;

    ArrayList<String> gPricesAsist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> afterUpdatePrices = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> changedPricesObjIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ObjIdsForNotifications = new ArrayList<String>();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    ArrayList<ParseObject> alPobjs = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
    ParseObject pObj ;
    String urlForUpdatePrice = "" , objIdToUpdate = "";
    String finalPriceForUpdate = "";
    String currentOldPrice="";
    int location;
    Date currentDate;

    String[] months = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    String[] monthsInNumsFormat = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"};
    boolean[] pricesWereChanged;

    String[] urlsForJsoup;
    boolean userHasFollowedItems = false;
    Document doc;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq;
    Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawr_layout);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
        fragmentIdFromIntent = getIntent().getIntExtra("fragmentIdFromIntent", -1);
        if(fragmentIdFromIntent != -1)
        {
            displayView(fragmentIdFromIntent-1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    public class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ThirdFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ForthFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

full home fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment 
{
    ArrayList<String> CompanyResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ModelsResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PricesResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> urlForImgResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> storeResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] types = {"Instruments"};
    int[] imgIds = {R.drawable.instruments_small_square_2};
    ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem> items = new ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem>();
    ArrayList<GridItem> gItems = new ArrayList<GridItem>();
    Context context;
    GridView homeGv;
    CustomAdapter gvAdapter;
    HomeFragmentGridViewAdapter hgvAdapter;
    ProgressBar pb;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    FragmentsComunicator fComunicator;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        Parse.initialize(context, "123456789", "123456789");
        homeGv = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.homeFragGridView);
        //pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "loading...");
        pb=  (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("WhicFragment?", "HOME FRAGMENT");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_instruments);
        GridViewCustomAdapter gvAdapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(context, R.layout.grid_view_item, gItems);
        gItems.add(new GridItem("Instruments", "289 items",bitmap));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_smartphones);
        gItems.add(new GridItem("SmartPhones", "coming soon..",bitmap));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_cameras);
        gItems.add(new GridItem("Cameras","coming soon..",bitmap));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_fridges);
        gItems.add(new GridItem("Fridges", "coming soon..",bitmap));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.small_laptops);
        gItems.add(new GridItem("Laptops", "coming soon..",bitmap));


        homeGv.setAdapter(gvAdapter);
        gvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        homeGv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {
                if(position == 0)
                {
                    //frame_container2  
                    //                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),InstrumentsActivity.class);
                    //                  startActivity(intent);
                    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, new InstrumentsFragment(), "InstrumentsFragment"); 
                    //ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit(); 
                }

            }

        });
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

full Instruments Fragment:

```
public class InstrumentsFragment  extends Fragment
{
    CustomAdapter gvAdapter;
    HomeFragmentGridViewAdapter hgvAdapter;
    ProgressBar pb;
    GridView homeGv;
    ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem> items = new ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem>();
    ArrayList<String> CompanyResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ModelsResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PricesResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> urlForImgResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> storeResults = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> resultIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instrumnets_frag_layout, container,false);
        context = getActivity();
        Parse.initialize(context, "123456789", "123456789");
        homeGv = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.instrumentsFragGV);
        //pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "loading...");
        pb=  (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.instrumentsPb);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i("WhicFragment?", "INSTRUMENTS FRAGMENT");
        container.removeAllViews();
        hgvAdapter = new HomeFragmentGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.home_frag_gview_item_layout,items);
        homeGv.setAdapter(hgvAdapter);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> pq = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("ClassicGuitars");
        pq.whereExists("Type");
        pq.setLimit(1000);
        List<ParseObject> pObjs = null;
        try 
        {
            pObjs = pq.find();
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(pObjs != null)
        {
            Log.i("parse_results", "pares object list in grid view is NOT null");

            for (ParseObject parseObject : pObjs) 
            {
                CompanyResults.add(parseObject.getString("InstrumentCompany"));
                ModelsResults.add(parseObject.getString("InstrumentModel"));
                PricesResults.add(parseObject.getString("LastUpdatedPrice"));
                urlForImgResults.add(parseObject.getString("UrlForImg"));
                storeResults.add(parseObject.getString("InstrumentUrl"));
                resultIds.add(parseObject.getObjectId());
            }
        }
        BgWork b1 = new BgWork();
        b1.execute();

        hgvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        homeGv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) 
            {
                Intent offersInent  = new Intent (getActivity(), Offers.class);
                offersInent.putExtra("actvSelection",
                        CompanyResults.get(position).toString()+" "+ModelsResults.get(position).toString());
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("companysArray", CompanyResults);
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("modelsArray", ModelsResults);
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("pricesArray", PricesResults);
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("companysUrls", storeResults);
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("imgUrls", urlForImgResults);
                offersInent.putStringArrayListExtra("ids", resultIds);

                startActivity(offersInent);

            }

        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();

        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
            {

                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainOptionsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private class BgWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            for (int  i = 0 ; i < CompanyResults.size() ; i ++)
            {
                HomeFragGridItem hgItem = new HomeFragGridItem(urlForImgResults.get(i).toString(),
                        CompanyResults.get(i).toString(),
                        ModelsResults.get(i).toString(),
                        PricesResults.get(i).toString());
                items.add(hgItem);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

adapter:

```
public class HomeFragmentGridViewAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<HomeFragGridItem>
{
    ArrayList<String> companys = new ArrayList<String>();   
    ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> stores = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem> mGridData = new ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem>();

    Context context;
    String url =""
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public HomeFragmentGridViewAdapter(Context context,int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem> mGridData) 
    {

        super(context, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mGridData = mGridData; 
    }




    public void setGridData(ArrayList<HomeFragGridItem> mGridData)
    {
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.guitarCompanyTv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gridViewItemCompanyTv);
            holder.guitarModelTv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gridViewItemModelTv);
            holder.guitarImg=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.gridViewItemIv); 
            holder.guitarPriceTv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.gridViewItemPriceTv);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        HomeFragGridItem item = mGridData.get(position);
        holder.guitarCompanyTv.setText(item.getCompany());
        holder.guitarModelTv.setText(item.getMoedl());
        holder.guitarPriceTv.setText(item.getPrice());
        //Log.i("parse_results", "*** 2 **"+(urls.get(position)));
        Picasso.with(context).load(item.getImage()).resize(140, 190).centerCrop().into(holder.guitarImg);       

        return row;
    }
    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView guitarCompanyTv;
        TextView guitarModelTv;
        TextView guitarPriceTv;
        ImageView guitarImg;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you got any error?

Comment: nope..no error.. @sasikumar , can the activity that changes fragments according to the nav drawer item pressed cause any problems..?

Comment: Better use .add() instead of .replace() and in your if() statement the .commit() is missing. I don't see anything else here :/

Comment: @An-droid , i tried add, it just mesees with layouts,, i suddenly see 2 fragments in the same screen.. and i do have commit,look closer..

Comment: Oh yes commit I see, and then again i don't see .addToBackStack(), maybe

Comment: @ bobby j commit is always required for fragment transaction to take place. Try calling container.removeAllViews() method in the onCreateView method if two views my overlap each other . Just give it a try

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal , container.removeAllViews() prevented the overlap of layouts , but the problem remains.. some Time the fragment is shown and some time it dosn't  i put a log inside InstrumentsFragment , and it's in the fragment , just the content (gridview of items) isn't displayed..

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57mk5w6ys0A

Comment: @ bobby j your code seems ok. try using childfragmentmanager while calling other fragments from a fragment. If this doesnt help you try updating question with full activity and adapter code

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal , i tried and got no view found for id exception..

Comment: @ bobby j ok can you post your full code of the activity and adapter?

Comment: sry I mean home fragment and adapter

Comment: @AbhisekLamsal i added

Answer (score 0):

I myself am a new in android,
but as well as i understand navigation drawer it itself is a fragment and when you are in a fragment and want to change a nested fragment you might need to call 
getChildFragmentManager() method instead of getFragmentManager()
this will need API 17 or above for below you can use android Support package

Hope This Helps..

Comment: i don't know if navigation drawer is considered a fragment by itself , it just conatins a conatiner theat swithces between fargmens, but anyway with your answer i get this exception:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id,  -i am not trying to display a nested fragment but to display a framgent NOT from the navigation drawer items!